# Counting letter occurences in a character array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

I have a project that asks me to count the occurence of letters in Java and for some reason the output of the program will only give me the occurance of the letter "a".  This is a problem that I do understand how to fix.

```
public String convert(String U) {

  int aCount = 0;
  int bCount = 0;
  int c = 0;
  int d = 0;
  int e = 0;
  int f = 0;
  int g = 0;
  // ...
  // removed for brevity

  char[] count = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

  char counting = U.charAt(i);

  for (i = 0; i > U.length(); ++i) {

    if (counting == count[0]) 
      aCount = aCount + 1;    

    if (counting == count[1]) 
       bCount = bCount + 1;

    if(counting == count[2]) 
      c++;

    if(counting == count[3]) 
      d++;

    if(counting == count[4]) 
      e++;

    if(counting == count[5]) 
      f++;

    if(counting == count[6]) 
      g++;

    // removed for brevity.
    // ...

    System.out.println(aCount + bCount + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z);
  }

  return"";
}
```

Comment: What does for (i = 0; i > counting.length(); ++i)  even mean? counting is a character, how can it have length. Did you even compile this code? and shouldn't counting=U.charAt(i) be inside the for loop?

Comment: Your `for` loop never runs, unless `U.length()` is magically less than 0....

Comment: You fixed the `counting.length()` to `U.length()`, congratulations, your `for` loop runs, the character you are counting should be inside the `for` loop now.

Comment: @Kartik_Koro the `for` loop runs? When is `i > U.length()`?  Surely not when `i` is 0 or 1.

Comment: @MikeKoch Oh my bad, I just noticed that he tried to find the length() of  a character I didn't even notice the wrong sign. Yes that has to be for (i = 0; i < U.length(); ++i)

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a new character each time the loop iterates and you are updating your counter for the `i` variable each iteration of the loop. It should be a different iteration index variable

```
// not here. INSIDE the loop
// char counting = U.charAt(i)
for( int index = 0; index < U.length(); ++index )
{
    char counting = U.charAt(index)
    if( counting == count[0] ) ++a;
    else if( counting == count[1] ) ++b;
    else if( counting == count[2] ) ++c;
    // ...
}
```

or you could use a foreach loop, which is more concise and make the intentions clearer.

```
for( char counting : U.toCharArray() )
{
    if( counting == count[0] ) ++a;
    else if( counting == count[1] ) ++b;
    else if( counting == count[2] ) ++c; 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always get as `counting` the char at position `i`. Well, `i` is an int (counting the occurences of character 'i', defined in your "removed for brevity" part, I guess), initialized as 0, so you always get the first character of `U`... I believe that your IDE has warned you about this...

Putting `counting = ...` inside the loop and changing `for (int i = ...)` to `for (int loopCounter = ...)` should fix this:

```
for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < U.length; loopCounter++) {
    char counting = U.charAt(loopCounter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: good catch with the `i`

Answer (score 0):

This line you have put outside  loop of iterating  `U` string

```
char counting = U.charAt(i);
```

this is why you are getting only `A's count`

keep it inside loop

and also use if else rather than if always.

so it should be like below

```
for (i = 0; i < U.length(); ++i) 
{
char counting = U.charAt(i);

  if (counting == count[0]) 
  {
    aCount = aCount + 1;    
  } 
  else if (counting == count[1]) 
    {
     bCount = bCount + 1;
    }
  else if(counting == count[2]) 
    {
        c++;
    }
// and so on

}
```

Comment: The `for` loop will never run in this scenario, as `i` is never greater than `U.length()`

Comment: And `i` is also being used as the iteration variable and counter for number of `'i'`s

Answer (score 0):

The sample program actually prints the sum or all lowercase character occurance. If that is the requirement then it could be simply done like (say the String is represented by str)

```
int charCountSum = str.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").length();
```

But if you want the individual character occurance of lowercase a-z then

```
Map<Character, Integer> occuranceCounter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
int count;
for(Character c : str.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").toCharArray()){
    count = 0;
    if(occuranceCounter.containsKey(c)){
        count = occuranceCounter.get(c);
    }
    occuranceCounter.put(c, ++count);
};

for(char c : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()){
    int times = occuranceCounter.containsKey(c) ? occuranceCounter.get(c) : 0;
    System.out.println(c + " occurs " + times + " times.");
}
```